# В случае отказа победителя от приза(,) будет заново проведена генерация

Tags: пунктуация

В случае отказа победителя от приза(,) будет заново проведена генерация случайного победителя.

Comment: Генерация победителя - это в смысле потомство?

Comment: Я бы подумал, что будет сгенерирован голографический образ победителя, которому организаторы символически вручат приз, а потом разделят его между собой. Можно так сказать: "... на основе метода генерирования случайных чисел будет выбран другой победитель".

Answer (score 1):

Причин поставить запятую нет. Это предложение не попадает ни в одну категорию, рассмотренную [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1/):

> **Обычно обособляются обороты**, которые:
>
> - располагаются между подлежащим и сказуемым
> - находятся не в начале и не в конце предложения
> - содержат объяснение того, о чем говорится в предложении, и выделяются интонационно

А вообще, *"в случае"* относится к оборотам с предлогами, которые "***могут обособляться или не обособляться*** в зависимости от приведенных выше условий", судя по той же ссылке.

Comment: Огромное спасибо)

Comment: Не за что.) Не забудьте галочкой принять ответ, если он Вас полностью удовлетворяет. Теоретически это может быть и не мой ответ, если кто-то другой ответит и Вам тот ответ больше понравится. Так что я не призываю Вас спешить с принятием, просто хорошо бы в итоге что-то принять (чей ответ принимают, тому баллы дают :) ).